# NInject chain of validators; aggregate implementing same interface

Tags: c#, ninject

I have this:

```
interface IValidator
{
  bool InputOK(Text);
}

class ValidatorChain : IValidator
{
  ValidatorChain(IEnumerable<IValidator> other_validators_in_order) {...}
  bool InputOK(Text) { return other_validators_in_order.All(v=>v.InputOK(Text)); }
}

ConcreteValidator1 : IValidator {...}
ConcreteValidator2 : IValidator {...}
ConcreteValidator3 : IValidator {...}
```

I want to bind this using ninject, easy enough;

```
Bind<IValidator>.To<ConcreteValidator1>();
Bind<IValidator>.To<ConcreteValidator2>();
Bind<IValidator>.To<ConcreteValidator3>();
```

Now, the problem is that i want to use the chain everywhere else, and just get the *chain* injected there. If i try

```
Bind<IValidator>.To<ConcreteValidator1>().WhenInjectedExactlyInto(typeof(ValidatorChain));
Bind<IValidator>.To<ConcreteValidator2>().WhenInjectedExactlyInto(typeof(ValidatorChain));
Bind<IValidator>.To<ConcreteValidator3>().WhenInjectedExactlyInto(typeof(ValidatorChain));
Bind<IValidator>.To<ValidatorChain>();
```

it seems to work at first, but I get cyclic dependencies, due to the last row. 
I made a few attempts at `When` on the last binding but didn't get it to work.

How can i solve this?

Edit: Also, I should add, I would like to not add any attributes to the classes.

Answer (score 1):

So, dto fix the cyclic dependency, the last binding should not be applied when the target itself is `ValidatorChain`.  This would be like, `WhenNotInjectedInto(typeof(ValidatorChain))`, which of course doesn't exist, but you can get the same by using `When` and checking the target type:

```
Bind<IValidator>().To<ValidatorChain>()
    .When(req => req.Target == null || req.Target.Type != typeof(ValidatorChain));
```

Ie, resolve to `ValidatorChain` when either the target is null (someone called `kernel.Get<IValidator>()`), or the target is something other than `ValidatorChain` itself.

Comment: I tried something similar to this, but it didn't work. A new attempt with your code verbatim (apart from namespaces etc) gave the same problem. It seems to ignore the "When" part; the chain appears as the last item in the IEnumerable. If I remove the line and specify that I want a specific ValidatorChain, it works.

Comment: @NiklasJ hm, that's odd - my tests with this were successful.  I copy/pasted your validator code, reproduced the cyclic-dependency error.  Adding the `When` clause fixed the error.

Comment: Ok. Most likely I'm doing something wrong. Maybe with some more info you may point me in the right direction: ASP.NET MVC 4.0 App, this validator is constructor injected into controller. The reference to Ninject says 3.0.0.0. The validator is in one project, the bindings in another, and the web project in a third. Initialized via NinjectWebCommon, I think untouched except for my change to BindingsProject.BindingsModule()

Answer (score 1):

Weird...
I played around with it and found that the following worked:

```
Bind<IValidator>().To<ValidatorChain>()
    .When(req => req.Target == null || req.Target.Type != typeof(IEnumerable<IValidator>));
```

This is of course not very robust, but in this case I have full control over the usage.
It looks as if target is the "requested type" rather than the "requesting object".